# Why does $(A^TA)^{-1} = I$ imply that $T_A$ is injective?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $T_A : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ be given by the matrix $\mathbf{A}$. I have been told A has a left inverse if $T_A$ is injective. Also, I have been told that $\mathbf{A}$ has a left inverse if $(A^TA)^{-1} = I$.

Therefore, I was thinking that $(A^TA)^{-1} = I$ must imply that $T_A$ is injective. If this is true, can anyone give an explanation of this implication?

Comment: A weaker condition: assume that $A^TA$ is invertible, i.e. $(A^TA)^{-1}A^TA=I$. That's all you need to make a conclusion that $A$ has a left inverse.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose $(A^T A)^{-1} = I$. Then $A^T A = I$. Hence $A$ has a left inverse ($A^T$). Therefore, $T_A$ is injective.